# Error converting python script to exe

Tags: python, windows, firefox, selenium, py2exe

I am using Python 3.4.1 on Windows 7 x86_64 system and I have a script that automatically downloads some data dumps from a website by using "Firefox" web browser for which I have written a python script.

Within the python script I am importing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os
```

I am also calling a ".bat" file from within the script using:

```
os.system("C:\\some_user\\Test1.bat")
```

I now want to create an ".exe" file for this so that it can be distributed to many machines without the need of having to install "Python" or "Selenium".

and i am using the following "setup.py" file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['Get_Data.py'])
```

where "Get_Data.py" is the script to be converted to exe file.

When I execute the command:

```
C:\My_Project>python3 setup.py py2exe
```

I get the output:

```
running py2exe

  3 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
Building 'dist\New_HPSM_Tool.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
```

And when I go to "dist" folder within C:\My_Project and execute "Get_Data.exe", I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Get_Data.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 43, in __init__
    self.profile = FirefoxProfile()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile
.py", line 64, in __init__
    WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\My_Project\\dist\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.jso
n'
```

What do I do to get an exe file. I am using "py2exe" as an amateur.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error says that the program cannot find the file in `C:\My_Project\dist\library.zip\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver_prefs.json`

Are you sure the directory and the file it is looking for is there?

Comment: Yes the directory does exist. But instead of the file named **"webdriver_prefs.json"**, there is a file **"webdriver.pyc"**. What should I do next?

Comment: It depends. If that file is the one you are looking for, then just modify the code to use that file instead. Otherwise, you will have to either look in another directory or maybe find the file on the internet.